# Symfony validate email without assert

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have made a simple Symfony form with only an email field. This form is used to send a document to a user. The form is not linked to any entity. Therefore the formtype looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'mapped' => false
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

So the email field is not mapped and this works fine.

Now I want to validate the email address like I do with other forms where I have the following asserts:

```
@Assert\Email(message = "email.not_valid", checkMX = true)
```

As this formtype has no entity I'm wondering how I can add the checkMX to the email field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#form-option-constraints

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => array(
                new Email(array('checkMX' => true)),
            ),
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

**EDIT** checkMx -> checkMX

Comment: Now I get the message "The options "checkMx" do not exist in constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email". Looks like checkMx is not part of the Email validation?

Comment: @Tom it's just a typo: `checkMx` should be `checkMX`